# How to use Slick's mapped tables with foreign keys?

Tags: database, scala, orm, persistence, slick

I'm struggling with Slick's lifted embedding and mapped tables. The API feels strange to me, maybe just because it is structured in a way that's unfamiliar to me.

I want to build a Task/Todo-List. There are two entities:

- Task: Each task has a an optional reference to the next task. That way a linked list is build. The intention is that the user can order the tasks by his priority. This order is represented by the references from task to task.
- TaskList: Represents a TaskList with a label and a reference to the first Task of the list.

  `case class Task(id: Option[Long], title: String, nextTask: Option[Task])`
  `case class TaskList(label: String, firstTask: Option[Task])`

---

Now I tried to write a data access object (DAO) for these two entities.

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._
import slick.lifted.MappedTypeMapper

implicit val session: Session = Database.threadLocalSession
val queryById = Tasks.createFinderBy( t => t.id )

def task(id: Long): Option[Task] = queryById(id).firstOption

  private object Tasks extends Table[Task]("TASKS") {
    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def title = column[String]("TITLE")
    def nextTaskId = column[Option[Long]]("NEXT_TASK_ID")
    def nextTask = foreignKey("NEXT_TASK_FK", nextTaskId, Tasks)(_.id)
    def * = id ~ title ~ nextTask <> (Task, Task.unapply _)
  }

  private object TaskLists extends Table[TaskList]("TASKLISTS") {
    def label = column[String]("LABEL", O.PrimaryKey)
    def firstTaskId = column[Option[Long]]("FIRST_TASK_ID")
    def firstTask = foreignKey("FIRST_TASK_FK", firstTaskId, Tasks)(_.id)
    def * = label ~ firstTask <> (Task, Task.unapply _)
  }
```

Unfortunately it does not compile. The problems are in the `*` projection of both tables at `nextTask` respective `firstTask`.

- `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
  scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapper[scala.slick.lifted.ForeignKeyQuery[SlickTaskRepository.this.Tasks.type,justf0rfun.bookmark.model.Task]]`
- `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapper[scala.slick.lifted.ForeignKeyQuery[SlickTaskRepository.this.Tasks.type,justf0rfun.bookmark.model.Task]]`

I tried to solve that with the following TypeMapper but that does not compile, too.

```
  implicit val taskMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[Option[Long], Option[Task]](
    option => option match {
      case Some(id) => task(id)
      case _ => None
    },
    option => option match {
      case Some(task) => task.id
      case _ => None
    })
```

- `could not find implicit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapper[Option[justf0rfun.bookmark.model.Task]]`
- `not enough arguments for method base: (implicit tm: scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapper[Option[justf0rfun.bookmark.model.Task]])scala.slick.lifted.BaseTypeMapper[Option[Long]]. Unspecified value parameter tm.`

**Main question: How to use Slick's lifted embedding and mapped tables the right way? How to I get this to work?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: Use ids instead of object references and use Slick queries to dereference ids. You can put the queries into methods for re-use.

That would make your case classes look like this:

```
case class Task(id: Option[Long], title: String, nextTaskId: Option[Long])
case class TaskList(label: String, firstTaskId: Option[Long])
```

I'll publish an article about this topic at some point and link it here.

Comment: Hi cvogt, is this limitation still in place for Slick 2.0? Do you have a reference as to how should this situation be sorted? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Did you publish your article ?

Comment: No, but it is still on my list and will probably happen some time until summer. I'll announce it on the Slick mailing list.

Comment: Did you publish the article?

Comment: Yeah, here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/orm-to-slick.html#navigating-the-object-graph